# Issue detecting when TCP listener has been closed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, deadlock

I am working on creating a custom TCP/IP client/server application, and have run into a snag when attempting to stop the server. Originally, my code used one TcpListener to listen on a designated port, and my (simplified for convenience) code to start and stop the server went as follows:

```
    private bool state;
    private TcpListener listener;
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
    private Dictionary<string, ConnectedClient> clients;
    private List<Task> clientTasks;
    private ConnectedClient command_client;

    public async Task RunServer() {
        if (!state) {

            state = true;

            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 55001);
            listener.Start();

            while (true) {
                try {
                    TcpClient socketClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    ConnectedClient client = new ConnectedClient(socketClient);
                    clients.Add(client.id, client);
                    client.task = ProcessClientAsync(client, tokenSource.Token);  
                    clientTasks.Add(client.task);


                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException) {
                    //Server stopped by user
                    //exit while
                    break;
                }
            }

            /* Server has been stopped; close all connections */
            CloseAll();
        }
        else {
            /* Stop the server */
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            listener.Stop();
            /* Clean up of currently connected clients is handled in CloseAll, handled upon ObjectDisposedException above */
        }
    }
```

ConnectedClient is a class I wrote to hold some info about individual clients for convenience and has a function that handles what happens when data is received. I realize I left some things out to streamline, but this code does exactly what I want it to do: the server waits for connections, creates a ConnectedClient object to handle connections received, and goes back to waiting. When this function is called when the server is already listening, the listener is stopped, which causes the listener to throw an exception, which breaks the loop and closes all connections.

The snag occurs when I attempted to create a server that listens on two different ports, which need to be treated differently.

Here is my code for (attempting) that:

```
    private bool state;
    private Dictionary<string, ConnectedClient> clients;
    private TcpListener command_listener;
    private TcpListener query_listener;
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
    private List<Task> clientTasks;

    public async Task RunServer() {
        if (!state) {

            state = true;

            tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            command_listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 55001);
            command_listener.Start();
            query_listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 55002);
            query_listener.Start();

            Task prevCommand = null;
            Task prevQuery = null;
            while (true) {
                try {

                    if (prevCommand == null || prevCommand.IsCompleted) {
                        prevCommand = waitForConnections(command_listener);
                    }

                    if (prevQuery == null || prevQuery.IsCompleted) {
                        prevQuery = waitForConnections(query_listener);
                    }
                    await Task.WhenAny(prevCommand, prevQuery);
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException) {
                    //Server stopped by user
                    //exit while
                    break;
                }
            }

            /* Server has been stopped; close all connections */
            CloseAll();
        }
        else {
            /* Stop the server */
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            command_listener.Stop();
            query_listener.Stop();
            /* Clean up of currently connected clients is handled in CloseAll, handled upon ObjectDisposedException above */
        }
    }
```

The purpose of waitForConnections is to handle connection requests so that waiting for a connection on one port doesn't block connections on the other, and also to ensure that only one connection can be made on port 55001.

```
    public async Task waitForConnections(TcpListener listener) {
        TcpClient socketClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

        if (((IPEndPoint)listener.LocalEndpoint).Port == 55001 ) {
            if (command_client == null) {
                command_client = new ConnectedClient(socketClient, onClientUpdate, onResend);

                clients.Add(command_client.id, command_client);
                command_client.task = ProcessClientAsync(command_client, tokenSource.Token);
                clientTasks.Add(command_client.task);
            }
            else {
                //only one client allowed on this port, reject the connection
                socketClient.Close();
            }
        }
        else {
            ConnectedClient client = new ConnectedClient(socketClient, onClientUpdate, onResend);

            clients.Add(client.id, client);
            client.task = ProcessClientAsync(client, tokenSource.Token);
            clientTasks.Add(client.task);
        }
    }
```

With this, I am able to connect clients on the two ports without blocking, but calling this function again and stopping the listeners does not seem to cause a ObjectDisposedException to be thrown as expected, which causes the whole program to hang and not do anything. I suspect this is being caused by some irresponsible use of asynchronous functions, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Your intended approach of forcing (and abusing) ObjectDisposedExceptions to indicate some form of connection termination looks completely wrong to me. Anyway, stopping a TcpListener object does not dispose it.

Comment: Fair, using exceptions to track state is bad practice I suppose. And as far as the disposal goes, I left that out for brevity because I didn't think it was relevant to the question. My real question, I guess, is why did the exception get thrown in the first case, but not in the second?

Comment: Sorry, again I was unclear. Why can't you read my mind? ;) in the first case, it threw the ObjectDisposedException with only the TcpListener.Stop() call, but in the second case, it does not. If stopping a listener doesn't dispose it, why would it have worked in the first place?

Comment: No, no, i think i slowly get what you try to do. So basically, you call `RunServer()` the first time, and somewhere somehow an ObjectDisposedException is thrown. Then you call `RunServer()` again, while *state* is still true, which will lead to invoking the TcpListner.Stop() method. And you expect Stop() throwing as well, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But the exception is not thrown until TcpListener.Stop( ) is invoked, which is caught and breaks the infinite while loop in charge of listening for connections. Maybe Stop( ) causes some other object to be disposed, and that is what raises the exception?

Comment: Now, first what object exactly is throwing ObjectDisposedException? You need to double-check this. TcpListener itself is not an IDisposable, so it itself will not/cannot ever throw ObjectDisposedException. Assuming the Socket object used by the TcpListnerer was throwing an ObjectDisposedException, then it might have caused the TcpListener to go into inactive/stopped state (you can check the `TcpListener.Active` property). Calling Stop() on an inactive TcpListener will not do anything...

Comment: Stop() more or less only closes the Socket object it uses. Unless your code messes with this Socket object directly, there should be no reason for TcpListener.Stop() to ever cause an ObjectDisposedException... (Stop() also creates a new Socket object for the TcpListener, but that should be irrelevant with regard to the exception)

Comment: I see, so the socket object was getting disposed, raising the exception. But my question remains, why doesn't it blow up in the second case? Is it something to do with it being put into a task instead of an outright await?

Comment: In the second case, do you await RunServer()? (Only then a possible exception will bubble up to the caller)

Comment: No, runServer is not awaited in either case. And it seems that stopping the listener does cause the AcceptTcpClientAsync in waitForConnections to abort/react as in the first case, but does not throw an exception. Instead, the status of the task being returned is set to "Faulted", which apparently counts as the task being completed, so program execution continues normally even though the listener is stopped. I would expect the listener to throw an illegal operation, but I assume that would just cause the task to fault and continue again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync() call is inside an async task instead of directly inside the loop, the exception that occurs when the listener is stopped causes the task to return with a status of "Faulted". Because the exception isn't caught, the loop continues, and a faulted task is considered a completed task, so it goes right back to trying to listen for connections despite the stopped listener (which in turn most likely causes the task to fault again).

Could have fixed this by checking for faulted tasks instead of catching the exception, but I instead chose to set a flag when I try to stop the server that breaks the loop and allows the program to close connections as intended.